# What files to be specified in IMAGE_BOOT_FILES for qemuarm machine while using wic create command

Tags: partitioning, yocto, qemu

I am pretty new to yocto,  I am trying to build a partitioned image using wic command for qemuarm ( Not for a real hardware ).

**Steps I followed:**

1. Created a core-image-minimal image for machine qemuarm.

   *bitbake core-image-minimal*
2. Using wic command to generate a partitioned image

   *wic create mywksImage -e core-image-minimal*

I use a custom wks file whose first line is as below

**part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk1 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4 --size 64**

Query:
When I run the wic create command above, i get below error
"ERROR: No boot files defined, IMAGE_BOOT_FILES unset for entry #1"

What files should be set for IMAGE_BOOT_FILES when the machine is qemuarm?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and found the solution here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#conditional-metadata
With the newest Yocto version you need to use `:` instead of `_`.

As qemu doesn't seem to use these files you can use any file name existing in `DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE` which is `build/tmp/deploy/images/qemuarm`. In your case your have to add this to the `local.conf`.

```
IMAGE_BOOT_FILES:qemuarm = "bzImage"
```

Running the final image should work with (https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/mega-manual/mega-manual.html#qemu-dev-command-line-syntax):

```
runqemu wic
```